# How to rationalise jqueryui functions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, function, syntax

I need help with syntax for rationalising jQuery / jQueryui functions for a form that uses a series of [jQueryui Sliders](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#default) to set input fields.

The form works fine, but I have two change listener functions that currently duplicate a series of jQuery actions, which I'd like to move into a shared, third function that they both call. The listener functions are:

1. If the form's 'exchange rate' input (type="text") is changed, the jquery .change() listens: `$("#ExchangeRate").change(function(){do a series of jQuery actions});`
2. If any slider is moved, the jqueryUI slidestop function listens: `$( ".slider" ).on( "slidestop", function( event, ui ) {do a series of jQuery actions}`

So, I'd like to move the duplicated series of jQuery actions into a custom .updateResults() function, so the listener functions simplify to something more like `$("#ExchangeRate").change(function(){$('.results').updateResults();});` and `$(".slider").on("slidestop",function( event, ui){$('.results').updateResults();});`. However, my attempts so far stop all scripts from running.

I'm quite new to jQueryui and am struggling to find documentation on the syntax needed for the calling jQuery action and the custom called function's basic structure. Can anyone please guide me to the appropriate docs, a worked example of jQuery functions calling custom jQuery functions or the correct search terms?
Thanks, Keith..

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like?

```
var updateResults = function () {
    $('.results').css('border', 'solid red 3px');
};
$("#ExchangeRate").change(updateResults);
$(".slider").on("slidestop", updateResults);
```

OR do you wish to make updateResults a jQuery plugin? (another question perhaps)

Comment: Thanks for the response Mark. I'd not seen a jQuery function declared as a variable before so searching for that I discovered what I think I need - the option 3 [Create your own jQuery Function](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/5-ways-declare-functions-jquery/). Best, Keith..